# Grails --- how to fetch data from Tomcat to my Grails app?

Tags: tomcat, grails

I've been using in my Grails app a MySQL database with hardcoded url, username and password in application.yml file.

Now the app is done and in deployment I'm supposed to get these data (url, usrname, pswd) from Tomcat.

From what I've researched, I'm supposed to do something like this (in application.yml):

```
${DB_URL:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname}
${DB_USERNAME:username}
```

But how to pass these data from tomcat level to my Grails app?

Comment: JNDI might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with doelleri.
I use JNDI with Wildfy to do what you want. I set the datasource parameters into Wildfly and use the datasource into my grails app.